# Hasura query nullable variable

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am trying to get superior id one by one from my database, but the last one will be allways nullable and i don´t know how to be able to ask in Int type varible for null value.

I tried this query which function untill i use the null value.

```
query GetSortHierarchy($device_id: Int!, $filter_id: Int!, $superior_id: Int) {
  devices_by_pk(id: $device_id) {
    filter_types(where: {id: {_eq: $filter_id}}) {
      sort_groups(where: {superior_id: {_eq: $superior_id}}) {
        id
        name
        rank
        sort_group {
          id
          superior_id
        }
        superior_id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with those variables

```
{"device_id": 156, "filter_id": 1, "superior_id": null}
```

And it returns this message
`"message": "unexpected null value for type 'Int'"`.

I know about `is_null` check but i would prefer single query and not two, one for null and second for the rest.

Comment: You are trying to use `is_null` without requiring a new query or you want a different functionality?

Comment: I am trying to find solution that would be just one query to do not use two query. So if you would know query that would help with is_null. I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the GraphiQL API explorer tool, hover over the `where` section and you should see a `$` button like so:

[image]

This allows you to supply the entire `where` section as variables. This will allow you to supply either filter type with the same basic query.

You can then have a `$sortGroupsWhere` variable (or whatever you choose to call it) that looks something like this:

```
{
  variables: {
    // ...other variables,
    sortGroupsWhere: {
      "superior_id": {
        // either: "_eq": "some_id"
        // or: "is_null": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will do it. Thanks, it simply moves my problem from a graphql query to creating my query in diferent language that allows me to write to it what i want. I used this method for update over many tables, but did not think of that for this request.